# How can I programmatically visualize a graph with manually positioned vertices on a headless machine?

Tags: visualization, headless

I need to generate frames of animation to visualize a new graph layout algorithm.  The frames will be generated on a server (50+ cores, 256GB RAM), but it is completely headless.

Every library that I have found wants to do the layout for me rather than allowing me to specify the position of each vertex manually.  Perhaps I have overlooked something, but my Google-fu has failed me.  My graphs are large; there will be millions of nodes and edges, and the graph structure will change over time, which is why I need to script the project.

I really don't want to waste a lot of time on the visualization, because that is not where the research is happening.

Does anyone know of a visualization tool that can work in a headless environment, that will allow me to specify the location of each vertex manually, and that can handle millions of nodes and edges quickly enough so that I can generate thousands of images?

Comment: Are looking for an SDK to embed in a application or a complete tool to deploy and do all the job for you?

Comment: Basically, I'm planning to have a file for each frame that describes the layout.  One part will be the (x,y) coordinates of each vertex, and then the second part will enumerate the edges that currently exist in the graph.  The image generation needs to be something that will be completely scripted, and it doesn't really matter what language it's in.  I just need to be able to tell the visualization library the coordinates and the edges.